# How to set max value for a variable without using an if statement

Tags: java

I'm required to set a max value for a variable to 100:

```
double area = length * width;       
if (area > 100) { //set parameters for area    
    area = 100;
}
```

How can I code this in a way that works and doesn't require the use of 'if statement'?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with an `if` statement?

Comment: Nothing. Exercise asks specifically to not use if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double area = Math.min(length * width, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks. this was exactly what I was looking for. We aren't allowed to use if statements yet because we haven't started studying it yet I guess.

Comment: I should give you fair warning, given that this is for an assignment: if you're not allowed to use `if` statements because you haven't learned them yet, I cannot guarantee you'd be allowed to use this either for the same reason.

Comment: We have covered Math, Scanner etc so it's fine. I'll double check to make sure though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `Math.min`, although I personally think it's less clear.

`area = Math.min(area, 100);`

Comment: It's a common enough idiom, though, that it will be clear to most readers.

Answer (score 2):

A ternary operator would work too:

```
double area = length * width;
area = area > 100.0? 100.0 : area;
```

If you don't mind calculating `area` twice, you can shorten this to a single line:

```
double area = (length * width) > 100.0 ? 100.0 : (length * width);
```